# The teachers do not allow [us/our] eating in the classrooms

Tags: grammar, verbs, verb-pattern

Does the verb 'allow" allow such structures as

1. The teachers do not allow us eating in the classrooms.
2. The teachers do not allow our eating in the classrooms.

Comment: The first is not grammatical, and the second is not idiomatic. Try this instead "The teachers do not **allow us to eat** in the classrooms".

Comment: Or "...do not allow eating".